# How can I get the ID before after_setup_theme?

Tags: hooks, add-theme-support

I need to get the ID of the currently edited post (in the WP admin) before the `after_setup_theme` is triggered, because what happens on `after_setup_theme` will depend on the currently edited post ID.

But seems like in my example post ID is still not defined at the time when `after_setup_theme` gets triggered.

How can I fix this?

How can I get and pass ID before `after_setup_theme` happens?

```
namespace Client\Theme\Config;
use Client\Theme\Template;

class Supports {

    const EDITOR_FONT_SIZES = [
        'normal'  => 18,
        'large'   => 25,
        'x-large' => 40,
    ];

    /**
     * Theme supports.
     *
     * @var array $supports
     */
    public static $supports = [
        'editor-styles',
        'title-tag',
        'automatic-feed-links',
        'post-thumbnails',
        'align-wide',
        'responsive-embeds',
        'disable-custom-colors',
        'disable-custom-font-sizes',
        'disable-custom-gradients',
        'editor-font-sizes'    => [],
        'editor-color-palette' => [],
        'html5'                => [
            'search-form',
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption',
            'style',
            'script',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Theme does not supports.
     *
     * @var array $remove_supports
     */
    public static $remove_supports = [
        'core-block-patterns',
    ];

    /**
     * Supports constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        \add_action( 'admin_head', [ __CLASS__, 'assign_sizes' ] );
        \add_action( 'after_setup_theme', [ __CLASS__, 'enable_supports' ] );
        \add_action( 'after_setup_theme', [ __CLASS__, 'remove_supports' ] );
    }

    public static function assign_sizes() {
        global $post;
        if ( Template::check_if_blog( $post->ID ) ) {
            foreach ( self::EDITOR_FONT_SIZES as $slug => $size ) {
                array_push(
                    self::$supports['editor-font-sizes'],
                    [
                        'name'      => ucwords( $slug ),
                        'shortName' => ucwords( $slug )[0],
                        'size'      => intval( $size ),
                        'slug'      => $slug,
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds various theme supports for this theme.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function enable_supports() {
        foreach ( self::$supports as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
                \add_theme_support( $key, $value );
            } else {
                \add_theme_support( $value );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removed unused theme supports.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function remove_supports() {
        foreach ( self::$remove_supports as $key ) {
            remove_theme_support( $key );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing that requires you to conditionally add theme support? This looks like you tried to solve a problem but your solution doesn't work, have you tried asking how to fix the problem rather than how to fix the solution? If you want different font sizes to be available to different posts this is not the way to do that

Comment: I am trying to display various settings and features only on the blog pages (blog home, archive, single post etc.). In this example, I want to make editor font size options available only on the blog pages.